# Updates filling internal storage

Tags: updates

I just bought a HTC desire626 not even a week ago . Seems like it updates all the time we'll now my internal memory is about full. Am I doing something wrong everything allowable to put on SD card but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Are you having the issue termed [tag:insufficient-memory]?

Answer (score 0):

Try going to 'Settings' and then go to apps/applications tab then go to 'all apps' you can then select the apps you do not require and then select uninstall, if you had the app already but it just updated it, it will just remove the update, but have factory version. Hope this helps.